# What is the table top runway maximum slope?

Tags: runways, airport-design

What is the maximum permissible slope for a table top Runway (elevation 1600 m) to be made on hill top ?

Comment: [Courchevel Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courchevel_Altiport) I believe is the steepest public-use runway with an 18.6% grade. Operating in that airport requires a special endorsement and training.

Comment: What country? What type of aircraft and operators? If there's no regulatory limit, there's probably a practical limit but it would depend on those details.

Comment: I think that's left up the pilot's discretion.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11857/62) might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Most Part-25 certified aircraft have an operating limit of roughly +/-2% for runway slope, as most of the runways fall into this category.

It would be probably possible to certify aircraft for steeper slopes, however at a significant cost, as the flight test program would have to be extended to collect sufficient data.

It is also worth mentioning that anything over 1% upslope requires a bit of a different flare technique as opposed to a flat runway. Usually a bit earlier flare with a bit late thrust reduction does the trick. Extending the limit beyond 2% would probably require additional training, as the flare characteristics would be significantly different than that at a normal runway.

Comment: Well, it is certainly possible to certify aircraft for steeper slopes, and some of them are, because there are places like VNLK (Hillary Tenzing Airport, Lukla, 12% slope) and LFLJ (Courchevel Altiport, over 18% slope).